# exit code + exit reason as string

Tags: java, node.js

On Windows, OSX, or *nix, is there a way to exit a process with a string "reason for exiting" as well as the standard exit code integer? I can map integer codes to reasons, but at some point there may be more than one reason for exit code 0, etc.

Comment: The only way I think would be to write the status message to stderr/stdout (or some known file).

Comment: Exit code zero always means "terminated successfully". There is no associated "reason".

Comment: Well, there is an associated reason from the developer's standpoint, but it's just not available at the systems software layer/level seems like. Which definitely seems like a mistake.

Comment: The only cure is to be really really diligent when pulling together your user specification that lists potential error codes. Leave a lot of gaps, and even more important: look how other products are solving this.

Comment: yeah, my main problem is that there are multiple reasons why my program would exit with code 0, in particular. So nothing solves this. Except more info. Lulz.

Comment: However, if I own the parent process (which I do), then I can use whatever codes I want, 0-10 could be ok, and anything higher could signal errors, etc.

Comment: Also note that using strings is a bad way to handle errors. Which language are these strings in? What if you run the program in a different locale? What if your initial release had a typo in one of the strings? If people need to write scripts based on your exit status, parsing strings is a bad idea.

Comment: @RealSkeptic you're probably right about that

Comment: Can you tell us what a couple of these different success scenarios are?

Comment: SUCCESSFUL_RUN: 0,
        WHOLE_TEST_SUITE_SKIPPED: 0,
        GREP_SUITE_DID_NOT_MATCH: 0,

Comment: this is a test runner, so the first is a successful run of the runner, the second is that the whole thing was skipped due to declarative code by the developer and the third is that a grep regex didn't match, so in essence the test file was skipped as well. and of course, in my case, skipped means a successful run.

Comment: I see, sort of warnings, could the caller specify through command line parameters to upgrade these warnings to errors? In which case they would return `!= 0` Or the other way round, specify a parameter to suppress errors around skipping or regex

Comment: well, regardless of what happens, I think that the mapping should remain constant; the only thing that might change is that stdout would show a warning or error, if the user specified a more verbose setting etc

Comment: Well it's the caller that cares about the exit code, it could decide if it cares about skipping tests or regex fails before calling, rather than afterwards.

Comment: yeah I know what you mean, this test runner has a lot of options and I am trying to limit the options because of info overload. Realistically, if a test gets skipped, there should be a warning, but I doubt anyone would want to bail the whole test runner if a test suite was skipped, just need to issue a warning and that warning would be clear, just need to use a different exit code than 0 I think, in order for that info to be passed between processes.

Comment: You may find that you want a lot more info from your test runner, like test counts, maybe the test runner should have a machine readable output log then you don't need to worry about trying to get all the info in a single integer exit code.

Comment: well, these are all node.js processes, and yes we can use IPC to send a lot of data between processes, but it is not guaranteed to happen before process shuts down, so using the exit code is cleaner and cheaper in some ways.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34627546/process-send-is-sync-async-on-nix-windows, process.send (IPC) is async now, so it is not guaranteed to complete if you call it right before process.exit..this is why it's best to call process.exit(theCodeYouWant)